# PHP array always return false with Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

I have this code in my Authentication.php (Controller)

```
public function check_user_name(){
    $userName = $this->input->post('UserName');

    $people = array();
    $people[] = array('UserName' => 'Junjun');
    $people[] = array('UserName' => 'Kent');


    if (in_array($userName, $people))
      {
        $result = array('result' => true);
      }
    else
      {
        $result = array('result' => false);
      }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

and i got my ajax code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

/*/
 * Declarations
/*/
var host = 'http://' + window.location.host + '<?php echo $this->config->item('base_folder'); ?>';
var txtUserName = $('#text-user-name');
var txtPassword = $('#text-password');
var btnNext = $('#button-next');
var btnLogin = $('#button-login');
var grpUserName = $('#group-username');
var grpPassword = $('#group-password');

/*/
 * Bindings
/*/
btnNext.on('click', btnNext_Click);


/*/
 * Events
/*/ 
function btnNext_Click() {
  event.preventDefault();
  //grpUserName.addClass('hidden');
  grpUserName.find('h1').text('Checking....');

  var post_data = new FormData();

  post_data.append('UserName', txtUserName.val());

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/pms/authentication/check_user_name',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: post_data, //post_data,
    success: function(data) { console.log(data);
      if(data.result == true){
        grpPassword.removeClass('hidden');
        grpUserName.addClass('hidden');
      }
      else{
        grpUserName.find('h1').text('Invalid User Name!');        
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });    
}
});
```

the problem in the console is it always returns false, what is wrong with my associative array? help please!

Comment: try `var_export( $_POST )` to see what it's real content is.  CI has a bad habit of lowercasing things.  All false means is, the item doesn't exist in `$_POST`

Comment: Your people array is structured wrong.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix where should i put that sir? and what post variable should i put inside the $_POST?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix i also think my structure is wrong, but i dont want to use the $people = array('junjun', 'kent'); thing

Comment: @OJT  - added an answer, that should illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit is wrong

```
$people = array();
$people[] = array('UserName' => 'Junjun');
$people[] = array('UserName' => 'Kent');
```

It will give you an array like this ( multi dimension )

```
$people = [
    ['UserName' => 'Junjun'],
    ['UserName' => 'Kent']
];
```

so `in_array` fails to find the key you are looking for.

```
 if (in_array("Junjun",[
    0 => ['UserName' => 'Junjun'],
    1 => ['UserName' => 'Kent']
])){ ... }
```

See "Junjun" is not equal to either of those 2 sub-arrays.  Instead just add them:

```
   $people = array();
   $people[] = 'Junjun';
   $people[] = 'UserName';

   //or
   $people = array('Junjun','UserName');
```

So your array looks like this

```
   $people = ['Junjun','Kent'];
```

Comment: IT WORKED! thanks mate, as what i also thought of my structure, damn, never thought thats what is happening, thanks for making it clear to me, and have a happy new year

Comment: You too, Glad I could help.  I get on here when I have an issue I cant fix... lol ... helps me think helping other people out.

Comment: for explanation  +1.

Answer (score 0):

> **Problem** : you are checking **in_array** condition with multi array
>
> **Solution**: You should change your people array something like below and it will work.

```
    public function check_user_name(){
        $userName = $this->input->post('UserName');

        $people[] = 'Junjun';
        $people[] = 'Kent';


    if (in_array($userName, $people))
      {
        $result = array('result' => true);
      }
    else
      {
        $result = array('result' => false);
      }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```